# Sheaf cohomology on quotient stacks

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quotient-spaces, sheaf-cohomology, algebraic-stacks

Suppose I have a scheme $X$ over $\mathbb C$, acted on by a finite group $G$. Let $\mathcal F$ be a $G$-equivariant coherent sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules.
Then I can form the stack quotient $[X/G]$, and $\mathcal F$ descends to $\mathcal F'$ on this stack.

Suppose that I know the dimensions of the groups $H^i([X/G], \mathcal F')$. What can I say about $\operatorname{dim} H^i(X, \mathcal F)$?

I know that $(H^i(X, \mathcal F))^G \cong H^i([X/G], \mathcal F')$, but ideally I'd like to know if there is something like an upper bound for $\operatorname{dim} H^i(X, \mathcal F)$.
If there is no answer in such generality, I'd be happy to know of special cases.

Comment: When $X$ is a discrete $G$-set (and $i=0$, since that's the only interesting cohomology group), you are asking for a bound of $|X|$ based on $|X/G|$. In this case, we have $|X|\le |G|\cdot |X/G|$. So the extremely naive guess would be that $\dim H^i(X,\mathcal F)\le |G|\dim H^i(X/G,\mathcal F')$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest example showing that no bound is possible is the following. Let $X = \mathrm{Spec}(\Bbbk)$ be a point, and let $F_1$ be the equivariant sheaf that corresponds to a non-trivial irreducible representation $V$ of $G$. Then
$$
H^0(X,F_1) = V,
\qquad\text{but}\qquad
H^0([X/G],F_1') = V^G = 0. 
$$
Now if you take $F_n = F_1^{\oplus n}$, the dimension of $H^0(X,F_n)$ grows with $n$ to infinity, while $H^0([X/G],F_n') = 0$ for all $n$.